# SQL Server - Full Text Catalog - Functionality / maintenance questions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, ssms, contains

I have a SQL query which is using CONTAINS and is not finding recently created records that it should be finding, for example...

```
SELECT Id, Title
FROM Books
WHERE CONTAINS(Title, 'Frankenstein')
```

...should find...

```
Id_____Title
321____Frankenstein
```

Older records are being found.

I believe this may be related to a full text catalog, (present in SSMS under DB > Storage > Full Text Catalogs), which has the table as an object, and has the Title column ticked as an eligible column. "Track changes" is set to automatic. The "Last Population Date" is over a year ago. The "Population Status" is "Idle".

My understanding so far, (which may well be wrong), is that the CONTAINS searchable terms are being controlled by the full text catalog, therefore perhaps if I rebuild, or repopulate it, the record will be found? Could I even schedule this to happen automatically to prevent this problem in the future?

The "Repopulate catalog" option on the full text catalog is greyed out. The "Rebuild catalog" option is not greyed out. I am concerned about attempting to perform either operation without fully understanding what they do... could you explain? I have already read the material around this subject on MSDN.

Thanks.

Comment: I have just double-checked, and exactly the same word is found in older records by CONTAINS but not younger records. In both titles, the word occurs first in the string, therefore the position within the string can't be anything to do with it.

Comment: It is certainly to do with the full text catalogue not being up to date.  Have a google for the various scheduled and automatic options and find one that works for your environment.